# How can I implement a react callback

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, callback

Im quite new to react and I am working on a registration page checkbox element

And below is the Choice component implementation,

```
const ChoiceItem = ( { options, itemId, selectedIndex, onChange } ) => (
  handleChange: function(checked){
    const value = [];
    options.map( option, i ) => (
      value[ i ] = checked;
    )

  },
  <Card>
    {
      options
      .map( ( option, i ) => (
        <Checkbox
          id={ `Choiceitem-checkbox-${ i }-${ itemId }` }
          key={ i }
          label={ option.text }
          style={ styles.checkbox }
          value={ '' + i }
          onChange={ ( checked ) => onChange( itemId, [ i ], checked ) }
        />
      ) )
    }
  </Card>
);
```

What I want to do over here is to loop through the options and get there values in to an array named value and call back the handleAnswerChange in registration form and set the value over there. Can anyone tell me how I can archive that?

 Thank you.

Comment: In your code snippet, you didn't bind `this` to your `this.handleAnswerChange`.

i.e. You should put `this.handleAnswerChange = this.handleAnswerChange.bind(this)` in your `constructor`. Otherwise, `this.setState()` should not work in your case.

BTW, in `renderItem()`, you didn't pass `props` into it.

Comment: @andre since `handleAnswerChange` is defined using an arrow function it is automatically bound. This does require using at least stage 2 in babel.

Comment: @kwelch oops, sorry, I didn't notice that s/he used arrow function, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the best solution for you is two way binding. You can check out the react docs on adding two way binding.

[react two way binding](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html).

Another option would be using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You are actually very close to having this one. I would update your `handleChange` in `MultipleChoiceItem`:

```
handleChange = (index) => (checked) => {
  const newValues = options.map((option, i) => {
    // if it is the changed returned the new state
    // otherwise just return the current value
    return index === i ? checked : option;
  });
  this.props.onChange(this.props.itemId, newValues);
};
```

Then inside of your render I would set the `onChange`:

```
onChange={this.handleChange(i)}
```

This should then update state on your `MyRegisterForm` on each checkbox click.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case there are 2 check boxes, is there a way to send an array in the handleChange function. In the above example the value will only get set if the check box is checked right? But I want to set the 2 checkbox values in an array in every on change.

Comment: I actually need the indexes of the check-boxes that are been checked to send to the register form to save as the answer. Im sort of stuck over there :(

Comment: The `i` passed in would allow you to attached it to each check box in the array. This would be called for both checked and unchecking. The variable checked will hold the status of check, I based it off your snippet.